# Proof that $t^8+2t^6+4t^4+t^2+1$ is reducible in $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, finite-fields

Prove that the polynomial $t^8+2t^6+4t^4+t^2+1$ is reducible in $\Bbb F_p$, for all $p\in \Bbb P$.
Here are some examples:
$t^8+2t^6+4t^4+t^2+1=(1 + t + t^4)^2\pmod{2}$
$t^8+2t^6+4t^4+t^2+1=(1 + t) (2 + t) (1 + t^2) (2 + 2 t^2 + t^4)\pmod{3}$
$t^8+2t^6+4t^4+t^2+1=(2 + t^2) (3 + 4 t^2 + t^6)\pmod{5}$
$t^8+2t^6+4t^4+t^2+1=(10 + 9 t + 3 t^2 + 2 t^3 + t^4) (10 + 2 t + 3 t^2 + 9 t^3 + t^4)\pmod{11}$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160847/polynomials-irreducible-over-mathbbq-but-reducible-over-mathbbf-p-for.

Comment: @Potato:Thank you very much!Could you show me how to compute the galois group of  $t^8+2t^6+4t^4+t^2+1=0$?

Comment: By hand? I do not know. The effective Chebotarev density theorem implies that you only need to check primes up to a certain bound in order to show an $n$-cycle never occurs, but I don't know what that bound is. It's probably very large. If all you want is the answer (and not a proof), I recommend using a computer algebra system.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Polynomials irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ but reducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for every prime $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160847/polynomials-irreducible-over-mathbbq-but-reducible-over-mathbbf-p-for) 
you should calculate galois group of this polynomial over $\mathbb Q$.
If you ask Magma:

> P:=PolynomialAlgebra(Rationals()); f:=x^8+2*x^6+4*x^4+x^2+1; G:=GaloisGroup(f); print G;

then you have

> Permutation group G acting on a set of cardinality 8
>   Order = 192 = 2^6 * 3
>       (1, 2, 3, 4)(5, 6, 7, 8)
>       (1, 2)(5, 6)
>       (1, 6)(2, 5)
>       (1, 6, 7, 8)(2, 3, 4, 5)

Now you should check that there are no 8-cycles in this group.
Most simple way is to generate all 192 elements and check.