# How is integer polynomial factorization reduced to factorization over a finite field?

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

I've read on Wikipedia that the problem of factoring polynomials over $\mathbb Z$ can be reduced to factoring polynomials over some finite field, but I can't find any information on how this is done. Would it be possible to get a "big picture", simplified description of what makes this possible, as well as a reference to a more detailed description?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen ["The case of the factorization of univariate polynomials over a finite field, which is the subject of this article, is especially important, because all the algorithms (including the case of multivariate polynomials over the rational numbers), which are sufficiently efficient to be implemented, reduce the problem to this case (see Polynomial factorization)."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields)

Answer (score 3):

Partial information can be obtained. Most notably, if a given polynomial $q(x)$ factors over $\Bbb{Z}$ like $q(x)=f(x)g(x)$, then it will have factors of degrees equal to those of $f$ and $g$ modulo every prime as well. This allows us to deduce irreducibility in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ in many cases:

- If $q(x)$ is irreducible modulo $p$ for some prime $p$, then it must be irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ as well.
- If the degrees of factors modulo different primes are incompatible, then again we can conclude that the polynomial is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$. For example a quartic that factors as a product of a linear and an irreducible cubic modulo prime $p_1$, and as a product of two quadratics modulo another prime $p_2$ cannot have any proper factors.

Search the site for examples!

On the other hand irreducibility over $\Bbb{Z}$ cannot be deduced from information about factorization over $\Bbb{Z}_p$. Not even if you include all the infinitely many primes. See [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/160847/11619) for examples of polynomials that factor modulo every prime, but yet are irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$. Qiaochu's answer in particular gives you bits and pieces about the related Galois theory.

---

[Edit:]

Another tool that occured to me is that of Chinese Remainder Theorem. The putative factors in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ need to be congruent to the modulo $p$ factors. This may force too large coefficients that can be ruled out by other means. As an example consider the polynomial
$$
q(x)=x^4-10x^2+1
$$
from the linked question. Modulo $7$ it factors
as
$$
q(x)=(x^2-x-1)(x^2+x-1)
$$
and modulo $11$ it factors like
$$
q(x)=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1).
$$
Could it have a quadratic factor $f(x)$ in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$? W.l.o.g. (Gauss' lemma) such a factor is monic, so
$$
f(x)=x^2+a_1x+a_0.
$$
The modulo $7$ factorization tells us that $a_0\equiv-1\pmod7$. But modulo $11$ information says that $a_0\equiv1\pmod{11}$. The Chinese Remainder Theorem then says that modulo $77$ we have 
$$a_0\equiv 34\pmod{77}.$$
Leaving it to you as an exercise to show that this forces $a_0$ to have too large an absolute value.

Unfortunately I do not know whether this kind of use of the CRT always gives something conclusive.

Comment: What about factoring over finite fields other than $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$? Can that be useful?

Comment: @JackM: I don't know. I have a copy of [von zur Gathen & Gerhard](http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Computer-Algebra-Joachim-Gathen/dp/1107039037) in my office, but I haven't studied it too closely.