# How to show the following polynomial is reducible

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Prove that $f(x)=x^4-10x^2+1$ is reducible modulo $p$ for every prime $p$

In order to show this I will have to show that $f(x)$ can be factored into two lower degree polynomials of degree $\le 4$.

But I am not getting how should I find the factorization.Please give some hints to proceed.

Comment: Reducible or irreducible?

Comment: for p=3 is also reducible

Comment: @Bernard;ques. edited

Comment: @CarryonSmiling I think it's $(x^2+1)^2$

Comment: @CarryonSmiling yes it is ..... you have mistaken ...$2x^2$ instead of $4x^2$

Comment: We where talking about $\bmod 5$

Comment: oh sorry @CarryonSmiling

Answer (score 3):

$x^4 - 10x^2 + 1$ has the following three factorisations: 
\begin{align*}
x^4 - 2x^2 + 1 - 8x^2 & = (x^2 - 1)^2 - 2(2x)^2 \\ 
x^4 + 2x^2 + 1 - 12x^2 & = (x^2 + 1)^2 - 3(2x)^2 \\
x^4 - 10x^2 + 25 - 24 & = (x^2 - 5)^2 - 6(2^2) 
\end{align*}
If $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, then the first is a difference of two squares, hence reducible.

If $3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, then the second is a difference of two squares.

If neither $2$ nor $3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, then their product $6$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, and so the third is a difference of two squares. Hence in all three cases, the polynomial is reducible.

Comment: Very nice ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: For a more general result see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160847/polynomials-irreducible-over-mathbbq-but-reducible-over-mathbbf-p-for).

Comment: So then it is always the product of two polynomials of degree $2$?

Comment: **One question**:::what was your aim while doing the factorisation? Did it came up just like that by brute-force method or you had some specific goal while doing it

Comment: The aim was to cover all primes (this method is often applied in number theory).