# Galois group of a general monic septic or octic polynomial.

Tags: galois-theory

How to determine Galois group of a general monic septic or octic polynomial.Could anyone suggest any reference material like some research paper or book.

Edit:Even a condition to decide the solvability of a septic equation would do.I already know that if it is solvable then it's Galois group is solvable and contained in semi product of Z_7 and Z_6.But I need a condition not related to Galois group as eventuallya I aim to find that only.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Dedekind's theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/160855/11619)? It gives a lot of information about the cycle types of element of the Galois group when viewed as a group of permutations of the zeros. I don't know if it gives enough information to always ID the group though.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen..This works really well in certain cases but wouldn't be of much help for a general criteria to distinguish between various Galois groups.