# There is an integer $l$ such that $f_l = x^{2^l}+1$ is reducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ for any prime $p$

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

So, the proposition is in the title, and the hint given is: show that $(U(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}),\cdot)$ is not a cyclic group if $n\ge 3$.

I proved the hint, noting the subgroups generated by $-1$ and $2^{n-1}+1$ are distinct and have both order $2$, which can't happen in a cyclic group.

Then I have the following solution that my past self wrote:

Suppose for contradiction that for any $l$ there is some prime $p$ such that $f_l$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$, then $\large\frac{\mathbb{F}_p[x]}{(f_l)}$ contains all the roots, i.e. $\alpha,\alpha^p,\dots,\alpha^{\large p^{2^l-1}}$. Then $\lvert U(\mathbb{Z}/2^{l+1}\mathbb{Z})\rvert = 2^l$ and it is forced to be cyclic, which is a contradiction by the hint.

Now, I agree with the fact about the roots, because of the Frobenius automorphism, but I just really don't see why $U(\mathbb{Z}/2^{l+1}\mathbb{Z})$ would be forced to be cyclic...

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77155/11619) we prove that $\ell=2$ has the required property.

Comment: And, as pointed out by Robert Israel [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/160847/11619), if you know that $f_2(x)$ is reducible, then trivially $f_\ell(x)=f_2(x^{2^{\ell-2}})$ will be reducible also.

Comment: Thanks Jyrki! That's a neat observation. And it's easy to see that $f_2$ is reducible over $\mathbb{F}_5$

Answer (score 0):

The group of invertible elements of a finite field is always a cyclic group.

[Finite subgroups of the multiplicative group of a field are cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59903/finite-subgroups-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-field-are-cyclic)

Comment: Yes Tsemo, but $\mathbb{Z}/2^{l+1}\mathbb{Z}$ is not quite a field

Comment: $F_p[X]/(f_l)$ is irreducible, so every subgroup of its group of invertible elements like $\alpha^i,...$ is cyclic.

Comment: Sorry Tsemo, but I'm not sure I follow. I think the group of invertible elements of $\mathbb{F}_p[x](\alpha)$ for $\alpha$ a root of $f_l$, is just $\mathbb{F}_p^*(\alpha)$. Can you please clarify why that has to be cyclic? Like, what's the generator?