# Showing that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2} \cdot \sqrt{3}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Well,

> I want to show that $f(x) = x^6 - 108$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, but I had no luck so far.

I tried to use Eisenstein criterion on $f(x+1)$ and $f(x+2)$ but it didn't work since the free coefficients doesn't suitable in both cases. I also tried to find a prime $p$ such that $f(x)\bmod p$ is irreducible, but it seems extremely inelegant.

Any other ideas?

Comment: For the general case $f(X)=X^n-a$ see other posts, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133581/when-is-xn-a-is-irreducible-over-f), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3777180/proving-that-xn-a-is-irreducible-if-a-is-no-p-th-power-for-any-prime-p?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is probably just to note that $\newcommand\Q{\mathbb Q}\Q(\sqrt3)\subset\Q(\sqrt[6]{108})=:L$ and $\Q(\sqrt[3]2)\subset L$. Thus, $[L:\Q]$ is divisible by $2=[\Q(\sqrt3):\Q]$ as well as by $3=[\Q(\sqrt[3]2):\Q]$, so $6\mid[L:\Q]$. At the same time, as you notices, $[L:\Q]\le6$ since it's generator satisfies a degree $6$ polynomial, so $[L:\Q]=6$ which means $x^6-108$ must be the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[6]{108}$, and so must be irreducible.

Answer (score 9):

Let's write $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{2} \cdot \sqrt{3}$.

Notice that $\alpha^2 = 3 \cdot \sqrt[3]{4}$ and $\alpha^3 = 6 \cdot \sqrt{3}$. Thus, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}$ has $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{4})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ as intermediate extensions. Since these fields are of degree $3$ and $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, respectively, we conclude that $6 | [\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}]$.

On the other hand, since $\alpha^6 - 108 = 0$, we know $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}]\leq 6$, so we conclude $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}] =6$ and the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ is degree 6. In particular, we must have that $x^6-108$ is the minimum polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

This answer merely regards proving irreducibility of $x^6 - 108$ , not using Galois theory. That this particular fact proves the assertion is obvious (following a standard theorem that the degree of the minimal polynomial equals that of the field extension), since $\alpha^6 = 108$.

Eisenstein will not work to show the irreducbility of this polynomial. I'll expand on this in my answer : this part will require Galois theory.

There's a simple prime $p$ with respect to which this is irreducible , though.

However, partly motivated by applications to Galois theory, there exist plenty (and I mean *plenty*) of criterion for irreducibility of integer coefficient polynomials. I'll mention one of these as well.

---

#### When doesn't Eisenstein work? (A general note)

Well, essentially speaking, we have this quantity called the discriminant of a polynomial : it's linked with the roots of the polynomial. If $P(x) = a_nx^n + ... + a_0$ has complex roots $r_1,...,r_n$ then :
$$
\Delta(P) = (-1)^{n(n-1)/2}a_n^{2n-2} \prod_{i<j} (r_i-r_j)^2
$$

is basically some power of the leading coefficient, times all the squared differences between each different pair of roots. (Note : if $P$ has repeated roots like $(x-1)^2$ then the discriminant is zero).

A nice geometric interpretation allows for some comfort : one may realize the given quantity as a discriminant of the gram matrix of a certain set of vectors sitting in $\mathbb C^m$ for some $m$ (actually $m$ is the size of the Galois group, but we won't talk about that). Either formula is convenient.

But the key result is the following (Theorem 3.3 from Conrad's notes present [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/math5230f12/handouts/totram.pdf)) :

> Suppose that $f(x)$ is a $p$-Eisenstein polynomial of degree $n$. Then if $p$ divides $n$, we must have $p^n$ divides $\Delta(P)$. On the other hand, if $p$ doesn't divide $n$, we must have $p^{n-1}$ divides $\Delta(P)$.

This helps us instantly eliminate a LOT of primes $p$ with respect to which this polynomial can be Eisenstein. In case you are worried about shifts : the discriminant doesn't change under shifts, nothing to worry about.

So all we have to do is find the discriminant. Easier said than done?

Yes : the discriminant is $2^{16}3^{21}$. If you're wondering, there is an easier way of finding the discriminant in *this* case : that's because you can write the roots of $P$ as $\omega^i \beta,i=0,1,...,5$ where $\omega$ is the sixth root of unity and $\beta$ is the unique positive sixth root of $108$. Using the root-based formula, the $\beta$s come out and the product simplifies into something involving the roots of unity, and you can use roots-of-unity type tricks to work things out.

But what this proves is : if the polynomial is Eisenstein, then it must be Eisenstein either modulo $2$ or $3$. Which may have looked trivial at first glance , but was worth expounding on anyway.

But clearly the polynomial can't be Eisenstein modulo either : recall that Eisenstein polynomials modulo $p$ must be irreducible modulo $p$ : however, whether it's modulo $2$ or modulo $3$, the polynomial $x^6-108$ reduces to $x^6$, which of course is reducible.

It follows that $x^6-108$ isn't $p$-Eisenstein for any prime $p$!

---

#### A remarkably simple criteria for irreducibility

The polynomial $x^6-108$ is irreducible. For this, we use another criteria using Vieta's formula.

> Suppose that a monic polynomial $P$ has complex roots $r_1,r_2,...,r_n$, and suppose that for each non-empty subset $S \subsetneq \{1,2,...,n\}$, we have that $\prod_{i \in S} r_i \notin \mathbb Q$. Then $P$ is irreducible.

Why? Well, suppose that $P(x) = p(x)q(x)$ for polynomials of smaller degree  $p$ and $q$. Then, using Vieta's formulas , we know that $p(x) = \prod_{i \in S'} (x-r_i)$ for some non-empty subset $S' \subsetneq \{1,2,...,n\}$, implying that $|p(0)| = \prod_{i\in S'} |r_i|$. The right hand side is irrational but the left hand side is rational, a contradiction.

In fact, it's enough to prove this for any $S \subset \{1,2,...,n\}$ with $|S| \leq \frac n2$. That's because we can WLOG consider the polynomial $p$ or $q$ of smaller degree, which can have at most $\frac n2$ roots.

To use this, we have to go for $|S| = 1,2,3$. For $|S| =1$ it's obvious that every root is irrational (since $108$ is not a perfect sixth power).

For $|S| = 2$, you have a product of the form $\omega^{i+j}\beta^{\frac 26}$. Each such number is a root of $x^6= 108^3$ : using the rational root theorem, such numbers are irrational.

For $|S| = 3$, you have a product of the form $\omega^{i+j+k}\beta^{\frac 36}$. Each such number is a root of $x^6 = 108^2$ : which is again always irrational by the rational root theorem!

The result follows. Note that it would have been difficult if , for example, some combination of roots would have given us trouble e.g. for $x^4+4$, the roots are given by $i^{j}\sqrt[4]{4}, j=0,1,2,3$, but if you multiply the roots corresponding to $j=1,3$ you'd get $2$. So you know that the criterion fails, and as it turns out the polynomial is reducible.

---

#### When does reducibility modulo $p$ not work? (A general note)

Reducibility modulo $p$, has also got a Galois flavour to it as well. This is a result that will look surprising. Of course, note that if $p$ divides the discriminant of $P$, then modulo $p$, the discriminant is zero i.e. there are repeated roots. The discriminant being zero will imply that $P$ will have a common root with $P'$, and hence a linear factor, a contradiction. So a polynomial $P$ can only be irreducible modulo $p$ for $p$ not dividing the discriminant of $P$. For those, we have this result.

> Suppose that $P$ is an irreducible integer coefficient polynomial, and $K$ is the field generated by the roots of $P$ (We know that $K/\mathbb Q$ is a Galois extension). Suppose that $p$ is a prime and that $P$ is irreducible modulo $p$. Then the Galois group of $P$ must contain an element of order $\deg f$.

So if the Galois group did *not* contain an element of order $\deg f$, then the polynomial is in fact reducible modulo $p$ for *all* $p$.

Can we write down the Galois group for $x^6-108$? After some effort, you'll notice that it's a group of size $12$ which , as it happens, contains a group element of order $6$ : Fail!

As a matter of fact, the polynomial $x^6-108$ is irreducible modulo $7$.

[Here is an example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3441666/is-x6-108-irreducible-over-mathbbq/3441689#3441689) where the criteria actually worked. I couldn't believe that it did. The technique used to prove irreducibility there, doesn't work here because you can't rule out simple factors. You may read the reference present there as well.

---

#### A lovely little side note

Using complex root positions and Vieta's formulas, you can try obtaining the following interesting result , Theorem 4.1 from the paper [here](http://www.hri.res.in/%7Ethanga/papers/mnl.pdf):

> Suppose that $P$ is a polynomial and $H = \max_{0 \leq i \leq n-1} \left|\frac{a_i}{a_n}\right|$ ($H$ is called the height). Then if there is $m \geq H+1$ such that $P(m)$ is a prime, $P$ is an irreducible polynomial.

The height of $x^6-108$ is $108$. So we can try to see if values of $P(m)$ are prime  from $m=109$ onwards. As luck would have it, $P(125) = 125^6 -108 = 3814697265517$ is prime. Done!

---

#### Irreducibility proving

Regarding irreducibility, essentially speaking there are some standard techniques that are used to prove this for polynomials. Very briefly :

- Reducibility modulo $p$ for a prime $p$ (Includes Eisenstein).
- Positions of the roots of the polynomial induced by abnormally large coefficients (like Perron's criterion).
- Constraining coefficients of factors using prime values at large inputs (Cohn's criterion, the height criterion, and so on).
- Newton polynomials , which use results that link root placement with the p-adic values of the coefficients to constrain coefficients of linked polynomials such as compositions, products etc. (Explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671738/explaining-newton-polygon-for-proving-irreducibility-of-polynomial-in-mathbbz)).

All these techniques contribute to Galois theory at our level, since they will be able to give us computational as well as ad hoc criteria for testing irreducibility.

Comment: it seems you've shown that $x^6-108$ does not have any roots modulo $7$, but this doesn't show irreducibility.

Comment: @BrianShin Good point : I'll edit the post. I can't believe I missed it. It's true, but I should have been careful.

Comment: @BrianShin I completed my proof using another simple criteria. I chose to focus on irreducibility. I wished to expound on other things regarding irreducibility, since the attempts made were in this direction.

Comment: Very cool, thank you!

Comment: @r0nnie Oh yes, thanks, my intention was to make this a post that was different from the others. Others use purely Galois-theoretic methods of proving irreducibility : I resolve to instead using simpler and more computable criteria. I hope my answer will do more justice than this mere question : you can try to apply the criteria I mention freely to a very large class of polynomials.