# From Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ to Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, galois-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $P\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$ be some polynomial. Let $p$ be some prime number. We can consider $P\in\mathbb{Q}_p[X]$. What informations can we get from the Galois group of $P\in\mathbb{Q}_p[X]$ to the Galois group of $P\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$? I imagine that only one $p$ is not sufficient for that so I guess that the correct question should be: what informations can we get from the set of all Galois group of $P\in\mathbb{Q}_p[X]$, for all $p$, to the Galois group of $P\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$?

For example the fact that $P$ is irreducible in one $\mathbb{Q}_p$ imply that it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$ so that the transitivity of the action of $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}/\mathbb{Q}_p)$ on the roots of $P\in\mathbb{P}_p[X]$ imply the transitivity of the action of $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ on the roots of $P\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Comment: I think, the amount of relevant information you can obtain will be limited, since the galois group of a Galois extension of $the $p$-adics is always solvable ,which is false for Galois extensions of the rationals...

Comment: But it seems that each finit group can be generated by solvable subgroups. It is maybe not hopeless...

Comment: Have you considered, for starters, the case $P = X^2-a$ for some $a \in \mathbb Q$?

Comment: To begin with, if $a\in\mathbb{N}$ without squared factors:

Comment: - if $p$ divide $a$: $X^2-a$ is Eisenstein hence irreducible, the extension is (totally) ramified and $\text{Gal}_p=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: - if $p$ not divide $a$: it's depend wether $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$:

Comment: - if it is then $X^2-a$ factor in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and hence $\text{Gal}_p=I$

Comment: - if it is not $X^2-a$ is irreducible, the extension is unramified and $\text{Gal}_p=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The Global $\text{Gal}$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$: So what is the philosophy here??

Comment: Let $K$ be the decomposition field of $P$: if $p$ is inert or ramified then for the only prime $\mathfrak{p}$ above $p$ one has automatically the decomposition group $D(\mathfrak{p})=\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$! not right? But we have $D(\mathfrak{p})=K_\mathfrak{p}$. Question: do we have $K_\mathfrak{p}$ (the completion) is the decomposition group of $P\in\mathbb{Q}_p[X]$?? If it is so all is done...

Comment: Excluding the ramified primes $p$ the factorization of $P$ in $\Bbb{Q}_p[x]$ reflects its factorization over $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$. Which, in turn, reflects the cycle structure of the Frobenius automorphism. Look up [Dedekind's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/160855/11619). If you are familiar with this, then I apologize for the waste of time. I just think that this is the natural connection between the two Galois groups.

Comment: Sadly my polynomial is not irreducible... but the proof of this theorem gives me some ideas: thanks to recall me this important result!