# Galois group of $x^4+px+p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I am able to show the Galois group over $\mathbb Q$ of $x^4+px+p$ where $p$ is a prime can be $D_4$ or $C_4$ if and only if $p$ is $3$ or $5$, but how can I show that it is exactly $C_4$ when $p=5$ and is $D_4$ when $p=3$.

Is there any way without solving the equation?

Comment: Do you have the explicit set of automorphisms?  When $p = 5$, does one of the automorphisms generate all of them under (self-)composition?  This should fail when $p = 3$ -- you should find one automorphism is an involution and the other(s) has(have) order $3$ ...

Comment: @EricTowers I don't have the explicit automorphisms... I need to compute them I think

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Standard" ways of telling if an irreducible quartic polynomial has Galois group C\_4?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38467/standard-ways-of-telling-if-an-irreducible-quartic-polynomial-has-galois-group)